# How to import facebook albums using php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was trying to import user's album after they are authenticated using oAuth2.
After getting user's information, I am using their id to get their albums.

```
$fqlResult=$facebook->api($user_profile['id']."/albums");
```

But this returns an empty array. I have also tried

```
$fqlResult=$facebook->api("/me/albums");
```

but it gives the same result.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer by Callum refers to Authenticated Referrals – a feature that only get’s called when the user clicks on any link leading to your app from within Facebook*.

But since you are handling the login to your app yourself, you’ll have to include the `user_photos` permission in the `scope` parameter when making the login, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

---

`*` I really don’t know why so many people keep confusing those two scenarios, or seem to have no idea how Authenticated Referrals actually work and what the according settings in the app dashboard do and what they *don’t* do …

Comment: Thank you for your correction - that's how we all learn. However, there's no need to be so arrogant. Consider pointing to relevant docs?

Comment: Didn’t want to be arrogant – sorry if I came across like that. Authenticated Referrals are a feature provided by FB to ensure users arriving at your app from some link inside FB (timeline posts etc.) will be already authenticated/connected to your app with the permissions you require. Since this authentication happens directly on Facebook, _before_ your app get’s actually involved, there is no way for you to specify the permissions with a scope parameter dynamically – therefor FB has provided developers with the option to specify these permissions inside the app settings already. […]

Comment: [Cont.] But that’s where many people seem to understand things wrong – these settings _only_ affect authentication in the described scenario, but _not_ any situation where you handle the login procedure yourself. In those latter cases, you’ll still have to specify the permissions yourself, via the scope parameter. Hope this helps to clarify things. The documentation for Authenticated Referrals is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals

Answer (score -1):

When the user authenticates your app, you need them to grant the `user_photos` permission.

To do this, go to your [App Dashboard](http://developers.facebook.com/apps) and click 'Edit App'. In the 'Permissions' section, add `user_photos` to the 'User and Friend Permissions' box.

Comment: Not just by making the query - the user actually has to grant the permission. This occurs when they use your app for the first time and they get the authorization dialogue. However, this will only need to happen when they first go to use your app. As soon as they authorize your app, the permission will be granted until such a time that they withdraw it.

Comment: I have changed the permission in app dashboard but i am getting this error. 

The web page at https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=223613824384257&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fusdev.findmespot.com%2Fspotadventures%2Findex.php%2Fcreate_adventure%2FimportFacebook&state=d94aea89fdc6b66f9c1b91f72c227f9e#_=_ has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Comment: when i click on fb icon to login

Comment: Have you already authorized your personal account (or, the one that you are logging in with) with this app? If so, it may help if you unauthorize it first, just to start with a clean slate.